# What is a good RAW File Processor/Developer/Editor for Mac?

Tags: macos, photos, graphics, switching

What is a good quality, and ideally free or cheap, RAW file processor for Mac OS X 10.7? Until I switched to Mac from Ubuntu, I used [RawTherapee](http://www.rawtherapee.com/), which served me well, but unfortunately it's not supported on Lion.

Ideally I'd prefer not splashing out on a pro-level graphics suite; I just want some basic abilities like exposure/color adjustment, aligning, etc. - with output to .JPG. If the tool also has a general photo management capability, great, but I can live without that.

I'm struggling to find anything that quite meets what I'm looking for. I tried [Raw Photo Processor](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/24692/raw-photo-processor), but the interface is cumbersome and confusing.

Comment: What kind of camera do you have? Canon and Nikon ship their own RAW processing tools with their cameras. I can't stand them but they're free.

Comment: Aperture from the Mac App Store is not free, but very affordable and good value for money.

Comment: Canon 400D, but it's sufficiently old I suspect the RAW tools aren't supported on Lion.

Comment: Apple's [Camera RAW](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4757) claims D400 support in OS X 10.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Apple iPhoto '11

Let's not forget that [Apple iPhoto '11](http://www.apple.com/ilife/iphoto/) costs $15 in the Mac App Store, and that it has processing tools for RAW as well as frequently-updated profiles for working with many makes and models of cameras that produce RAW image files.

### Google Picasa

[Google Picasa](http://www.google.com/picasa/) is free and supports many RAW formats.

### Canon Digital Photo Professional

version 3.11.26 is compatible with Mac OS X Lion. If you already own an earlier version that came with your Canon camera, you can download the updater from canon.com for free. Otherwise, here is how you can get it:

[Canon Digital Photo Professional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Photo_Professional) comes on a CD with a suite of programs called **Canon Digital Camera Solutions Disk** ver. 38.1.

I recently bought a used Canon Powershot G10 whose seller did not provide the original software sold with a new Canon. So I called up Canon's customer service, explained that I bought a used Canon, and asked them if I could purchase their tools on CD. They sold me the suite for US **$20** plus tax and shipping (it came to **$27**).

> ...you may purchase the latest Canon Digital Camera Software Solutions
>   disc for your camera through Canon USA's Customer Support Center at
>   1-800-828-4040. Residents of other countries should contact their
>   regional Canon customer support center for further assistance.

I installed the whole suite on Mac OS X Lion, then downloaded the latest updates from canonusa.com to make sure they were compatible with Lion.

The suite includes **Canon Digital Photo Professional**, for processing RAW images, a batch-file processing utility called **Canon Digital Photo Professional Batch**, the **Canon Image Browser** for general photo management, and **Photostitch** for making panoramas.